# Formatting datetime stamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a data frame with an index that is a DateTime stamp. I would like to change it by formatting the index. I have to use strftime to apply but when I used to like this it doesn't work.

```
df.index = df.index.map(strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
Error: 'strftime' is not defined
```

But it work just fine when I do like this:

```
df1.index[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I would like to apply for all my index. Suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, need [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```